# Understand important features in UMAP

Tags: clustering, optimization, dimensionality-reduction, tsne

I am using a dimensionality reduction algorithm (UMAP) to cluster high-dimensional data.

Particularly, I have ~50000 vectors of dimension ~20000 to visualise. These vectors are highly structured: They lie on low-dimensional manifolds, which I don't know. Because of this reason, UMAP is able to cluster them perfectly: I can easily see the clusters and they match exactly the shape I was expecting.

I know that, among the ~20000 entries of every vector, only a few of them actually play a role in the final dimensionality reduction. I just do not know which ones. In other words, most of the features are useless and do not contain much information, and I would like to find out which ones are them and cancel them out.

Is there a way to understand which entries are important in the final prediction?

Comment: Is it single-cell transcroptomic data? If yes, this https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/557967v4 might be relevant. Github link: https://github.com/alexisvdb/singleCellHaystack

Comment: mmmm no, but I'll have a look to what you suggested anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @Alfred Did you find the answer to your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possiblity - that seems in a sense a bit backwards, but would probably work - is to use some model to predict the UMAP embedding and look at what features play a role in the prediction.

Since the the embedding is potentially a highly non-linear transformation, I would think about using a neural network (either with some normalization before hand - e.g. rankgauss - or a batch normalization as the first layer, followed by a few dense layers) and having a look at which of the inputs are get meaningful activation for any of the examples.

Other prediction tools that can deal with non-linear transformations such as xgboost/LightGBM etc. may be even better options, because they do not need input normalization and allow easy interogation using [SHAP values](https://github.com/slundberg/shap).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [sparse pca](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#sparsepca). Then you can look at the nonzero coordinates of the first `n` components, this will tell you which features explain the most variance.